# Getting "program type already present: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager"

Tags: android

When I am running my Android app on my app the compiler gives the below error

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging 
dex archives: 
C:\Users\xxx\xxx\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar,
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to 
complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
```

[image]

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you got this error!

Comment: @ShivamKumar there no error in code .Its compile time error

Comment: @ShivamKumar check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsdce.png

Comment: Can you run project before

Comment: yes  sir am running lots of time

Comment: then what are you add when comes this error

Comment: Cardview with listview

Comment: Can you share your code of listview

Comment: which one file java or xml

Comment: i think error in java file

Answer (score 0):

Try going into gradle scripts, in build.gradle under `buildTypes{
}` and add this line `multiDexEnabled true` and then sync Gradle.

For example :

```
buildTypes {
   release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

Comment: Sir please help

Comment: Click on "Run tasks" and take a screenshot

Comment: @AndroidMan, check on your screenshot, there is somewhere it's written "Run tasks" in red. Click on that arrow it should list some errors

Comment: Was it working before? if yes delete the build folder C:\Users\CLA\IGText\app\ and then rebuild the app or create a new project and migrate your files module by module

Comment: yes but im adding listview with cardview then its not woking

Comment: I can see this is just the OneFragment code, it guess it's called somewhere. right? Don't you have any activity in your project?

Comment: no i have only one activity and also all fragments but i working on this fragment only

Comment: so post your MainActivity code and check if that activity is set as launcher activity in the manifest

Comment: post its code here @AndroidMan we need full understanding

Comment: here statckoverflow showing me some error when i am posting code so i created this file for that.sorry

Comment: you can use external link i will take time to review it

Comment: sorry sir please i have this problem so manage it,and please solve it

Answer (score 0):

if You use google play services com.google.android.gms:play-services:... 
change it to new version and

clean and rebuild the projeet

Comment: clean and rebuild project

Comment: add your dependancy file screenshot